# Homological orientation vs. smooth orientation.

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds

Assume that $M$ is an $n$-dimensional smooth manifold. Although I have seen many threads and online handouts dealing with these two different ideas I cannot understand what makes them equivalent. Why the choice of continuous local orientation implies smooth orientation for $M$? The definitions I am using  are the following

$\mathbf{1.)}$ Smooth orientation for a manifold $M$ is a maximal atlas $\{ (U_{\alpha}, \phi_{\alpha}) \}_{\alpha \in A}$, such that the transition map $\phi_{\alpha} \circ \phi^{-1}_{\beta}$, $\forall \alpha, \beta \in A$, has positive Jacobian determinant.

$\mathbf{2.)}$ Local (homological) orientation for a smooth manifold $M$ is the choice of generator $[M]_x \in H_n(M,M-\{x\}) \cong \mathbb{Z}$, $\forall x \in M$. We call such a choice continuous, if for every $x \in M$, there exists a neighbourhood $x \in U \subset M$ and a class $a \in H_n(M,M-U)$, such that the inclusion $(M, M-U) \to (M,M-\{x\})$, induces a homomorphism $H_n(M,M-\{x\}) \to H_n(M,M-U)$ which sends $a$ to $[M]_x$. A continuous local orientation for $M$ is called homological orientation.

Comment: I find the explanation here really solid:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientability

Comment: I have already checked that, I didn't find an answer unfortunately. I can't see the real relation between them.

Comment: I can't see how the local orientation determines an orientation of M.

Comment: It would be helpful if you included in your question the exact two definitions you would like to compare.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$2 \to 1$

Pick a homological orientation for $M$. Fix a generator of $H_n(\Bbb R^n, \setminus \Bbb R^n \setminus \{0\})$ (equivalently, make sure you know what orientation on $\Bbb R^n$ you're using).

For a chart $\varphi_\alpha: U_\alpha \to \Bbb R^n$ with $\varphi_\alpha(x) = 0$, note that there is an induced map $(\varphi_\alpha)_*: H_n(U, U - \{x\}) \to H_n(\Bbb R^n, \Bbb R^n \setminus \{0\})$. Because $\varphi_\alpha$ is a diffeomorphism, $(\varphi_\alpha)_*$ is an isomorphism. The inclusion map $H_n(U, U - \{x\}) \to H_n(M, M - \{x\})$ is an isomorphism by the excision theorem.

We say $(U_\alpha, \varphi_\alpha)$ is an oriented chart if the composite $$H_n(M, M - \{x\}) \xrightarrow{i^{-1}_*} H_n(U, U - \{x\}) \to H_n(\Bbb R^n, \Bbb R^n \setminus \{0\})$$ sends your chosen generator of the first group to the fixed generator of the last group.

The relevance of the positive Jacobian condition is that a diffeomorphism $f: (\Bbb R^n, 0) \to (\Bbb R^n, 0)$ preserves the generator of $H_n(\Bbb R^n, \Bbb R^n \setminus \{0\})$ if and only if $\det \text{Jac}_0(f) > 0.$ In fact, if you have a smooth map $f: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n$ sending $0$ to $0$, it is homotopic to $\text{Jac}_0(f): \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n$, given by setting $f_{1-t}(x) = \frac{f(tx)}{t}$ and $f_1(x) = \text{Jac}_0(f)(x)$; this is a continuous homotopy of $f$ that sends nonzero points to nonzero points as long as $f$ did the same. (If $f$ did not, restrict to a smaller open set where it did and run the same argument: remember that excision allows us to do this whenever we want.) Now we just need to see the induced maps of linear maps; because $GL_n(\Bbb R)$ has exactly two components, determined by their determinant, we just need to check the induced map of *two* linear maps. The identity induces the identity; a reflection induces $-1$. (Use the long exact sequence of the pair $(D^n, S^{n-1})$ and the interpretation of the map on top homology as degree in $S^{n-1}$.)

Thus the induced map on $H_n(\Bbb R^n, \Bbb R^n \setminus \{0\})$ is the sign of $\det \text{Jac}_0 f$. As long as you choose your charts to preserve the homological orientation, your transition maps will always have positive Jacobian determinant.

$1 \to 2$

Same recipe as above: this time the rule is that you choose the generator of $H_n(M, M - \{x\})$ using an oriented chart (as opposed to determining which charts are oriented using where the generator goes).

Comment: That's a good answer, y'all.

Comment: Mike thank you very much, it seems to be a good answer indeed. As I said at the comments, my main problem is the $2 \to 1$. When you have a smooth manifold $M$, then you already have a maximal chart. Of course, this doesn't mean that you have an orientation. However, picking a homological orientation for $M$ forces us to construct a new maximal chart which is oriented. I can't see how this construction goes. What's the relation with the one we started in the first place?

Comment: @user430191 You start with a maximal atlas. What I have given you is a recipe to determine which charts in that atlas are "oriented", and thrown out all the ones that aren't. Now the transition maps between these "oriented" charts have positive Jacobian determinant.

Comment: @MikeMiller thank you for your effort. I shall work it out, and probably come up later if I don't understand. Cheers!

Comment: Sure thing. As a remark, in some sense exactly half of the charts are "oriented" and the other half are "non-oriented". The collection of all "non-oriented" charts (but no oriented charts) would again form an oriented basis, now with the opposite orientation.

Comment: Perhaps it pays to be pedantic here: you have a maximal atlas, then you throw out the charts which aren't oriented. You now have to be careful how you define "orientation", because the maximal atlas containing the charts you kept is just the original one!

Comment: @SteveD Thanks, it took me a second to parse that but it's a good point: I assume at the start you have taken a maximal atlas containing all the charts you can find, no discussion of Jacobians on overlaps. When we pick the "oriented charts" as above, we have formed a new atlas, not maximal in the previous sense (I could just reflect any chart to get a new one), but maximal with respect to adding more charts whose transition maps have positive determinant w/r/t the existing ones: it is a maximal *oriented atlas*.

Comment: Thanks Mike. It was unclear from the OP's description and the other comments here if they were aware of the slightly difference between a "maximal oriented atlas" and an "oriented maximal atlas" :)

Comment: @SteveD nice point, there was indeed an ambiguity from the definition. An orientation for $M$ is the choice not of a maximal atlas, but an atlas where every chart is oriented. My problem is that I don't see how this atlas forms a covering for $M$. After throwing out non-oriented charts, may be points not covered by the remaining charts in this oriented atlas.

Comment: @user430191 Write $r: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n$ for the map which negates the first coordinate. If $\varphi: U \to \Bbb R^n$ is a chart, $r\varphi$ is a chart with the same domain and opposite orientation. And in fact every unoriented chart can be obtained this way, because $r^2 = \text{Id}$. This is the justification for the 'half of your charts are oriented/unoriented' claim.

Comment: @MikeMiller so the idea is that you start with a maximal atlas, you keep all the positively oriented charts and with the negatively oriented we make this "trick" which makes it positive and we end up with a covering. This resulting covering (which is an atlas in fact) is the seeking orientation. Am I right?

Comment: I'm not doing a trick to the negatively oriented charts, just showing you that the positively oriented charts covered M. That used that it was a maximal atlas (so $r\varphi$ was already a chart). If you have some arbitrary atlas (not maximal), then yeah, instead of throwing out negatively oriented charts, replace them with a positively-oriented one.

Comment: @MikeMiller ok I see, I got it know I think. Really appreciate the time you put and your effort.